# add information to a text file

Tags: unix, text, append

I have a text file and I would like to insert in the middle of the text some more text.
I have got this input text:

```
[etc....] 
relay_recipient_maps =
                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_yoda,
                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_luke,
                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_rd2d2,
                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_c3p0,
                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_dark_vador 
[etc...]
```

After the last line, I want to insert Anakin after "the dark vador line", but I haven't any idea how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `GNU sed`. Run like:

```
sed -f script.sed file.txt
```

Contents of `script.sed`:

```
/relay_recipient_maps =/,/[^,]$/ {

    /relay_recipient_maps =/ n

    /[^,]$/ {
        s/[ \t]*$/,/
        a\                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_anakin
    }
}
```

or:

```
/relay_recipient_maps =/,/[^,]$/ {

    /btree.*[^,]$/ {
        s/[ \t]*$/,/
        a\                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_anakin
    }
}
```

Results:

```
[etc....] 
relay_recipient_maps =
                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_yoda,
                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_luke,
                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_rd2d2,
                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_c3p0,
                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_dark_vador,
                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_anakin
[etc...]
```

Comment: THANK you, but after Dark_vador, Anakin take the last line of the "relay_recipient_maps" block. How to retrieve the last line of dynamic manner, and add a new item in the list

Comment: yep, it's may be a good question :)
I noticed that there are keywords like "btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_" and "," to isolate the last line. But I do not know bash script ....

Comment: A very good question ... in the results I list above, would you like the dark_vador line to end in `,` also?

Comment: After the "Darth Vader" there is a line "," and Anakin becomes the last line does not ",".

Comment: Someone told me to look on the side of postconf

Comment: @pi-2r: ok I've fixed it. I'll just add it to my answer now. Thanks for being patient. `sed`'s not my strongest language.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the script works fine except on 2 conditions. In fact, after the "relay_recipient_maps" block, I'have got many other blocks. THere are 2 blocks with the following syntax:
"disable_vrfy_command = yes" and "smtpd_helo_required = yes". The script adds the line ("btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_anakin") after the keyword yes .... How to resolve this bug ?
Thank in adavance :)

Comment: @pi-2r: Just a quick question, are you using the latest version of the script or the version you tried 17 hrs ago? I made a couple of changes earlier today (10 hrs ago) to make the matching a bit clearer.

Comment: Yes,I used the last version. Moreover, I noticed that if I use two consecutive script, indentation is no longer respected. I do the following operation:
- "sed-f script.sed main.cf | cat> test.cf" and "sed-f script.sed test.cf | cat> test2.cf"

test2.cf in, I get a bad indentation is as follows:
relay_recipient_maps =
                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_yoda,
                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_luke,
                btree :/ opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_anakin
,
  btree :/ opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_anakin

Comment: @pi-2r: Don't forget to accept the answer if your are happy with it. Upvotes are always appreciated too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what shell you are using.
You can do this within bash, zsh and maybe some others:

```
echo "the dark vador line" >> file_with_content.txt
```

This will append the string to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed:

```
sed -e '/dark_vador/ s/$/Anakin/' file.txt
```

For every line that contains the pattern `dark_vador`, the string `Anakin` will be appended to the end of the line.

If you only want to do this for the first match, you can quit after appending:

```
sed -e '/dark_vador/ { s/$/Anakin/; q }' file.txt
```

The `s` and `q` commands must be grouped together so they are only executed on lines that have `dark_vador`, otherwise `q` would quit after the first line read (even if it doesn't contain `dark_vador`).

If you would like to append a line **after** the `dark_vador` line, you can use the `a` command:

```
sed -e '/dark_vador/ a\
Anakin' file.txt
```

This will create a new line with `Anakin` after every line with `dark_vador`. As above, you can quit if you only want to add a line after the first match:

```
sed -e '/dark_vador/ { a\
Anakin
q }' file.txt
```

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 0):

This is a GNU sed alternative:

`sed '/^relay_recipient_maps/,/[^,]$/{/btree:.*[^,]$/s##&,\n                btree:/opt/pmx69/postfix/etc/vdm_valid_users_Anakin#}' file.txt`

How it works:

For the block started with "relay_recipient_maps", and for all subsequent lines till one not ending with comma, then substitute the "btree:" line not ending with comma (this would be the last btree in the "relay_recipient_maps" block) with that same line plus "," and the new line desired.

This assumes the "relay_recipient_maps" block always ends with a btree: line not ending with ","